# Data base in php

Tags: php, html

I wrote this code and I sure that all of things in code and server are correct but it isn't work!!
what's wrong ?!

```
<?php
  $id = isset($_POST["id"]);
  $decrease = isset($_POST["dis"]);
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
  $select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");
  if ($decrease=='10%')
    $q1 = 'update book set Price=Price-Price  * 0.1 where ID="$id";';
  else
    $q1 = 'update book set Price=Price-Price* 0.3 where ID="$id";';
  $b = mysqli_query($conn, $q1);
  $query = "select * from book where ID = '$id';";
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
  $r = mysqli_fetch_row($res);

  print("<table border='1'><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td>               </tr>");  
  echo '<td>'.$r[0].'</td><td>'.$r[1].'</td><td>'.$r[2].'</td>';
?>
```

Comment: Not `$id = isset($_POST["id"]);` but rather `$id = (integer) $_POST["id"];` so that (1) you don't get the `boolean` result of `isset()` in `$id` and (2) you prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\Works\New Text Document.php on line 2

Comment: And change `"$id"` to `"'.$id.'"` in your querys, too. Question on `Notice: Undefined index` Was the form posted, if not, the error is right. Because when not posted there is no `$_POST['id']`.  Please learn the basics of coding and form handling in php.#

Comment: Undefined index this mean your not Post the id to the page

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the `isset` values to your variables, which means it will always be true or false. Instead, use `isset` in an if statement, then run everything else below it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["id"]) && isset($_POST["dis"])) {
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    $decrease = $_POST["dis"];
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
    $select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");
    if ($decrease=='10%')
        $q1 = "update book set Price=Price-Price  * 0.1 where ID='$id'";
    else
        $q1 = "update book set Price=Price-Price* 0.3 where ID='$id'";
    $b = mysqli_query($conn, $q1);

    $query = "select * from book where ID = '$id'";
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $r = mysqli_fetch_row($res);

    print("<table border='1'><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td>               </tr>");
    echo '<td>'.$r[0].'</td><td>'.$r[1].'</td><td>'.$r[2].'</td>';
} else {
    // Do something else if it hasn't been posted
}
?>
```

Pay attention to the change in quotes here as well. Variables are not processed in single-quoted strings, so you need to change to double-quoted strings on your update lines. However, it's really best to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bind_param instead, so you don't need to worry about quoting or SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

1. first issue

   ```
   $id = isset($_POST["id"]);
   ```

`isset()` function will return true or false based on array element availability.

The correct way would be

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
{
  $id = $_POST["id"];
}
```

2. Issue

   ```
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','');
   $select = mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");
   ```

correct syntax for mysqli_connect is:

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
```